# Как отсортировать коллекцию?

Tags: c#

Есть коллекция:

```
public Dictionary<string, Element> Files = new Dictionary<string, Element>();  

public class Element
    {
        public string FolderName { get; set; }
        public string Path { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

Можно ли отсортировать коллекцию по Path?

Нужно получить новую коллекцию, в которой элементы будут отсортированы по возрастанию по "Path"

Comment: Files.OrderBy(x=>x.Value.Path)

Comment: Эээ... А что вы называете словом «отсортировать»? Какой видимый эффект должен получиться?

Comment: @RusArt: Ну, вы получите новую коллекцию, причём другого типа, а что станет со старой?

Comment: @VladD Ну это еще не коллекция, а вообще не совсем понятно что конкретно надо.

Comment: @RusArt: Воооот!

Comment: Нужно получить новую коллекцию, в которой элементы будут отсортированы по возрастанию по "Path"

Comment: @АлександрПузанов Может так: `Files.Values.OrderBy(x=>x.Path).ToArray()`?

Comment: Как я понимаю, нужно переопределить метод Equals класса Element, в котором определить правила сравнения объектов типа Element. И там прописать как сравниваются Path. А как сортировать словарь по значению см. здесь: http://www.cyberforum.ru/csharp-beginners/thread695087.html

Comment: RusArt, пойдет ваш вариант.А как сортировать по возрастанию/убыванию?

Comment: OrderBy/OrderByDescending. @RusArt, оформите как ответ.

Comment: Странно, но коллекция не сортируется...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Сортировать значения словаря по возрастанию и сохранить в массив:

```
var ordered = Files.Values.OrderBy(x=>x.Path).ToArray()
```

И по убыванию:

```
var orderByDescending = Files.Values.OrderByDescending(x=>x.Path).ToArray()
```

Comment: Что-то не могу понять... В двух вариантах у меня коллекция не сортируется. Все ее элементы по прежнему в том же порядке.

Comment: @АлександрПузанов словарь, он же Dictionary<Key, VAlue>, понятия не имеет о порядке элементов и не должен об этом знать. Вам предложили способ получить отсортированную коллекцию. Вот этот результат и передавайте в отображающий контрол или что там вместо него, а в самом словаре все останется на прежних местах. Либо используйте коллекцию с поддержкой сортировки Sorted<что-то>

Comment: Сортировка только по ключу будет согласно вашего комментария.

Comment: @АлександрПузанов да, в случае SortedDictionary сортировка будет по ключу. Сортировка по произвольному полю с сохранением результата только в обычном массиве, List или LinkedList

Comment: Спасибо, разобрался. Ваш комментарий - это лучший ответ. Воспользовался List.